# How to make a checkbox checked automatically based on a value in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, checkbox

Currently, I want to make the Checkbox checked automatically based on a value from Firebase. How to make it without the use of window.onload function?

Note: I am using HTML and javascript

I had tried onchange, onload

```html
<div class ="container1">
  <center>
    <label class="switch">
       <input type="checkbox" id="lbtnStatus1" value="" onclick="btnClick()">
       <span class="slider round" ></span>
     </label>
   </center>
</div>
```

Code that reads from Firebase:

```
firebase.database().ref("/appliance_table/").once("value", function (snapshot) {
    var lroom_light1 = snapshot.val().lroom_light01;
});
```

Comment: which code do you you to get value from firebase?

Comment: Normally i get value by using javascript, this is the code    firebase.database().ref("/authentication_table/").once("value", function (snapshot) {
      var email = snapshot.val().Email;
      var password = snapshot.val().Password;
      
      document.getElementById("username").value = email;
      document.getElementById("password").value = password;
  });

Comment: So which value you use to check the checkbox?

Comment: Sorry posted wrong, i had updated. the lroom_light1 contains either on or off.